# Delete all fields in huge mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, bigtable

I have a lot amount of db, now i need to delete some table, where is many data, about millions, but if i delete using sql syntaxis, phpmyadmin interface, or delete table, i still have some data after refreshing. How to delete clear all data in table?

Comment: Is anything adding data to your table?

Comment: `DELETE FROM yourtable`? SQL's nice in that the less you specific, the more you get. If you don't put any limits on a query, you ever everything - in this case, delete all rows.

Comment: Do you want to delete the data in the table, or the table itself?

Comment: @MarcB but it doesn't, i still have from 100 to ~2000 entries in table

Comment: @pavelby: unless those rows are locked for some reason, they would have had to be inserted into the table AFTER the delete operation completed. MySQL doesn't just skip some rows because it's having a bad hair day.

Comment: What about [`TRUNCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html)?

Comment: @JamWaffles yes, truncate solve, but delete still have magic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to ensure you get a table wiped is to use the `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name` statement. If you still have data in the table after that, it means something is constantly adding data to the table.

Comment: moreover - truncate is clearing table much faster, than DELETE. Delete clears row-by-row, Truncate - simply recreates table, dropping older.

Comment: `TRUNCATE` also skips the rollback-log and other stuff. It's benefits are many, it's dangers as well ;)

Comment: if than i create a new table, as before, it will have some data!

Comment: New tables are always empty, until someone/something adds data to them.

Comment: @Jocelyn that's it! it must be empty, but after delete sql, and deleting table, and recreating it, it have data! it's magic! with small tables all ok

Comment: ok, thank you, with truncate now is ok, but delete gives magic)

Comment: one more question: why after truncate i still have space used by this tables on hard drive? table is empty, but why space is not free? how to do this?

Comment: @PavelBY the table's metadata will take up disk space. Also, some table engines will pre-allocate disk space for faster/smoother operation later on, so they'll consume significant space even if the table's actually empty.